# Como fazer cada elemento de um array de números multiplicar cada um dos seus dígitos dentro de uma substring?

Tags: javascript

Vim de Python e estou tentando criar uma função cujo objetivo é calcular o maior produto para uma substring contínua de dígitos de comprimento N.
*Ex: para o input '102181952', o produto maior para uma série de 3 dígitos é 90 (9 * 5 * 2)*

Eu tentei criar dois loops com for (array[i][j]) igual em Python, porém não obtive sucesso. O máximo que consegui até agora foi, ao menos, criar um array de substrings. Tentei usar map e reduce, porém não obtive êxito, muito provavelmente porquê não sei manusear bem as funções, embora eu tenha lido os documents e pesquisado extensivamente por aqui em inglês e português.

Até agora o que eu consegui fazer, e acho que nem servirá de nada foi simplesmente:

```
// Ainda não coloquei dentro de uma function(numero, tamanho) 
// para fins de monitoramento.

var numero = '123456789';
var tamanho = 3;
var listaNumeros = [ ];

for (var i = 0; i < numero.length; i += tamanho) {
    listaNumeros.push(numero.substr(i, tamanho));
};

console.log(listaNumeros); // [ '123', '456', '789' ]
```

Alguém poderia ao menos me apontar a direção correta para a solução? Eu simplesmente estou em branco, não consigo pensar em mais nada. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um caminho não se preocupando com validações e isso é um exemplo minimo:

```js
var numero = '102181952';
var tamanho = 3;
var listaNumeros = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numero.length; i += tamanho) {
  let s = 1;
  const n = numero.substr(i, tamanho);
  for(var j = 0; j < n.length; j++) {
    s *= parseInt(n[j]);
  }
  listaNumeros.push({n, s});
};

console.log('Resultado:')
console.log(listaNumeros.sort(function(a,b) { return b.s - a.s })[0]);
console.log('Item gerados:')
console.log(listaNumeros);
```

como queria o maior valor foi executado um `sort` do maior para o menor e indicado a primeira posição, como disse é um exemplo básico que pode te ajudar a criar um exemplo bem melhor.

Comment: Isso é um ótimo começo para mim, irei ver se consigo aperfeiçoa-lo. Agradeço imensamente.

Comment: Só um pedido a mais, cajo seja possível: eu estou ainda na transição de aprender a usar arrow functions apropriadamente, por isso tentei fazer uma 'engenharia reversa' com a sua, mas não consegui. Você sabe me dizer como ficaria o 'normal' do `listaNumeros.sort((a,b) => b.s - a.s)[0]`? No caso eu tentei `listaNumeros.sort(function(a, b) {return (b.s - a.s)[0]});` e o código roda, mas não funciona como pretendido. Muito obrigado, e desculpe-me.

Comment: Mudei está na resposta @AlecsanderCamilo